# HMAC a struct with openssl

Tags: struct, openssl, hmac

I wonder if there is a simple way to HMAC a struct with openssl, I was thinking about concatenating all of the struct fields into one buffer, but I'm not sure it is the best/optimal way.

I hope you can help me figure this out,

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Wondering how to do something is not a real question on Stack Overflow. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 0):

HMAC outputs a hash (byte array) from input of another byte array. So - effectively you need to make a byte array (or multiple arrays) from your structure.

The important thing is - your structure should be unique for unique data. What I mean is - having two fields with values "abc" "def" or "abcd" "ef". If you just concatenate the values, you will get "abcdef" in both cases and it could be possible to authenticate wrong message. A solution could be putting some constant values as field separators.

Comment: Which raise another problem, What if a field value contains a field separator?

Comment: The constants don't need to be the same. Indeed, I can imagine a way how to spoof such an array :)  A fieldname (unique name) separator is better then a single constant value.

Comment: Field name doesn't solve the problem. Imagine you have an object "field1":"abcfield2", "field2":"def". You can de-serialize it to "field1":"abc", "field2":"field2def".

Comment: I just dropped a warning, it's up to you to make the serialization unique :D (adding field length prefix, escaping, encoding, ..)